# Error while installing a tar.gz package in R

Tags: r, r-package, nlopt

When i try to install a R package **nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz** from http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz , using  **sudo R CMD INSTALL nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz**,
 I get the following Error :

> Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
>   unsupported entry type ‘’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **not** an R package!

If you perform the tar, zip dance:

```
tar xvfz nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz
```

and look at the README, you get:

> NLopt is a library for nonlinear local and global optimization, for
>   functions with and without gradient information.  It is designed as as
>   simple, unified interface and packaging of several free/open-source
>   nonlinear optimization libraries.
>
> The latest release and a complete manual may be found at the NLopt
>   home page: http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt
>
> It is compiled and installed with the standard GNU autoconf/automake
>   commands:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```
>
> -- snip --