# Error while installing "nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz" from local

Tags: r, unix, ubuntu-14.04, r-package

When i tried to install **nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz** from local, It needed another unix library **nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz** which I got it resolved from the following thread [Error while installing a tar.gz package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303688/error-while-installing-a-tar-gz-package-in-r)

But, even after that the package is not getting installed
It throws the following error,

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/nloptr/libs/nloptr.so':
  /home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/nloptr/libs/nloptr.so: undefined symbol: nlopt_set_maxtime
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/nloptr’
```

For the above error, I got a lead from the following link:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL
and
 http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Installation

Based on the above links, I had to set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** variable to */usr/local/lib* and */usr/local/include*

Even after setting the above Environment variable, **R CMD INSTALL nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz** is not getting installed and throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is easy. On a Debian/Ubuntu system do

```
sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev
```

as you *always* need the *development* package to *compile* a given library.  It will then be found, and `nloptr` will install without a hitch.

Similarly on a RH/FC/CentOS with rpms.

Now, when I helped Jelmer rewrite the configuration for nloptr, we did make sure it worked both ways: *with* an install nlopt library, and without.  You seem to stuck in  the middle with one that is installed, but different ("missing symbol").  If you cannot uninstall that 'wrong' libnlopt, I would recommend altering the nloptr sources to *not* check for it but rather always build itself against a copy of nlopt 2.4.2 which it will download and compile statically.